# Прописная или строчная в названии гос. органа?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Служба национальной безопасности Узбекистана

Vожно ли писать *служба* со строчной? Ведь министерство экономики можно писать со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

СЛУЖБА НАЦИОНАЛЬНОЙ БЕЗОПАСНОСТИ РЕСПУБЛИКИ УЗБЕКИСТАН, правильно писать как

> Служба Национальной Безопасности Республики Узбекистан, СНБ Узбекистана

Comment: 17 - 4 = 13 часов. Раньше вопрос выглядел иначе. Исправленный - конкретней и, тем не менее, с опечаткой. Может быть, правя, оставлять и первоначальный текст (для справки)?

Comment: Прошёл ещё день. Vожно ли писать со строчной v?